# Authentication error when calling Graph via Blazor Server application

Tags: c#, azure, graph, azure-active-directory, blazor

I'm having some trouble calling the Graph API from a Blazor Server application. I've followed the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=azure-resource-explorer but I'm getting the following error when trying to login:

***MsalClientException: One client credential type required either: ClientSecret, Certificate, ClientAssertion or AppTokenProvider must be defined when creating a Confidential Client***

My code is as follows:

```
appsettings.json

{
  /*
The following identity settings need to be configured
before the project can be successfully executed.
For more info see https://aka.ms/dotnet-template-ms-identity-platform 
*/
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Graph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
}


program.cs

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


SearchBase.cs

[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
public class SearchBase : ComponentBase
 {
     ...

     protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
         try
         {
            _user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            _logger.LogDebug(ex.Message);
         }
     }

     ...
 }
```

The error fires when initially logging into the application. It looks to be getting triggered by the last three lines in the program.cs file:

```
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

If I comment them out it logs me in via Azure AD as expected. That however leads to the Graph API call in the SearchBase.cs not working.

I'm very new to using Graph API, hopefully someone has come across this before. The examples I've found via Google return code that is pretty similar to my own so I'm at a loss as to what's going wrong.

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Mark

Comment: try this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph/blazorserver-calls-MS-graph

Comment: Thank you, that helped. The issue was that I hadn't set up and sent a client secret. Looking closer at the examples I followed it looks like they were set up as web applications hosted in Azure, so possibly didn't need one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***MsalClientException: One client credential type required either: ClientSecret, Certificate, ClientAssertion or AppTokenProvider must be defined when creating a Confidential Client***

This error usually occurs if **ClientSecret** parameter is missing while calling Microsoft Graph API.

To resolve the error, you need to include the **ClientSecret** generated by your **App Service** in the `appsettings.json` file.

You can get the **ClientSecret** value like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> App Services -> Your App Service -> Authentication -> Identity Provider Settings -> Edit*

[image]

Select ***"Click to edit secret value"*** like below:

[image]

Copy the value of your **Client Secret** like below:

[image]

Now, update your **`appsettings.json`** by including copied **Client Secret** like below:

```json
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Graph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. That was the issue, all sorted now.